# What are the differences in physics between $( | 0 \rangle + |1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and $( | 0 \rangle - |1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, superposition, quantum-states

They are clear mathematically. The first state is the result after a Hadamard gate is applied to 0; the second 1.

If we don't measure them, we know nothing about them? If you do, they have the identical probability amplitude, thus we still cannot tell their differences.

Of course, we can apply a Hadamard gate again to each, then we know the former comes from 0; the latter 1. But, if we don't know their origins, how can we tell the essential differences of those two states in physics?

Take photons as an example. Do they represent two states of polarization?

Comment: We have MathJax running on the site, so you can get $\left(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>\right)/\sqrt{2}$ by putting `\left(\left| 0 \right> + \left| 1 \right>\right)/\sqrt{2}` between dollar signs. Though for the purposes of the title you could also just ignore the normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any further context, there isn't any difference because you can always redefine $|1 \rangle$ by a sign to go from one to the other.

But once you fix the definitions of $|0\rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$, there is a difference. For example, if $|0 \rangle$ represents photon polarization along the north direction and $|1 \rangle$ is along the east direction with appropriate phase, your two states could represent polarization along the northeast and southeast directions, which are easily distinguishable.

Comment: Shouldn't the direction of the $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ states always be antipodal on the Bloch sphere? Why is it valid to define them in not opposite directions?

Comment: @LeoL. A basis doesn't have to be orthogonal. Any two non-parallel vectors in a two-dimensional vector space form a basis (and hence can generate any vector in that space). An orthogonal basis is simply a nice thing to have that's easy to work with, not a necessity.

Comment: @probably_someone oh right, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @LeoL. The Bloch sphere is a visualization tool for spin $1/2$ systems, where orthogonal states correspond to spins in opposite directions. Other systems are visualized differently.

Comment: @knzhou Can you provide an example system where it is advantageous to choose the basis such as the one you provided above?

Comment: @LeoL. Photon polarization _is_ an example. The states $|0 \rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$ defined in my answer are orthogonal.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "...which are easily distinguishable."? Could you please show me a link somewhere to educate me about it? I am quite new in this field. Do you mean there is an "easy" technique in physics to determine a certain photon's polarization directions while the photon is in a quantum superposition after the H gate is applied?

Comment: @EmscriptenFan Just put a polarization filter with the axis northeast. A northeast photon always gets through, a southeast photon never gets through.

Comment: @EmscriptenFan Or, let's think about this more generally. Do you think there's a way to distinguish between any polarizations at all, like north and east? I bet you do, since otherwise your question wouldn't have made sense! Just take whatever that way is, and rotate it by $45^\circ$, and now you have a way to tell between northeast and southeast.

Comment: @EmscriptenFan You can describe all possible photon states using the linear-polarization basis, which consists of a vertically-polarized state and a horizontally-polarized state (this is far from the only basis in common use; another common example is the set consisting of a clockwise circularly polarized state and a counterclockwise circularly polarized state). A vertically-oriented linear polarizer will let a vertically-polarized photon through and block a horizontally-polarized photon. By measuring the probability of detecting a photon after a polarizer, you obtain its state up to a phase.